# steering wheel shakes in a turn

Tags: ford, brakes, steering

I drive a 2011 Ford F150.  After new tires, new brakes and rotors and a wheel balance, the truck rides fine at all speeds and braking is good.  However, when I enter into an exit ramp and brake while in a turn, my steering wheel shakes and doesn't stop until after I am in a straight away for a few minutes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you had an alignment done of the vehicle?

Answer (score 1):

If Your Wheels are aligned and brakes are good then there are a few things you need to check.

1. Check needle bearings.
2. Check if power steering is normal.
3. Check if the lug nuts on the wheels are proper.
4. Check your camber alignment.

I googled and it seems this vibration is a frequnt problem on the F150. 
Usually it is the U-Joints which give way causing the vibrations.

You can check this by jacking up your front end, turn the steering wheel all the way to one side and spin your tire by hand (spin and let go). If it spins real nice then the ujoint isn't the issue. If the ujoint is bad your tire won't spin good or might even stop and go the other way.

Also, if you have any fine red dust around the ujoint bearing caps that is a sign the grease inside the ujoint is all dried up and needs replaced.